# Laptop's internal keyboard as an external one?

Tags: laptop, usb, keyboard, ps2

Firstly, let me say that I've never seen how a laptop's internal keyboard interface with the motherboard. Hence the question.

The thing is I use an external keyboard and monitor, but I like how internal keyboards are, and I simply can't find a decent external keyboard that makes me happy.

So it just occurred to me if it could be possible to interface an internal keyboard through USB or PS/2, so I could use it as an external one... and so I could be happy once and for all.

**Followup:**
If anyone wants to know, I ended up buying [this keyboard](https://www.siig.com/usb-mini-multimedia-keyboard.html) which has a key-layout exactly like a laptop's. It hasn't the touch feel of a real laptop's keyboard (it's noisier), but that was the best I could find at that time.

Comment: In laptops, the keyboard controller circuitry is located on-motherboard, so the keyboard connects directly with a matrix cable. While there's no technical reason why someone couldn't make a USB controller suitable for laptop keyboards, I'm not aware of any company that does so.

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Typing on the flat table might not be so handy with a laptop keyboard...

Comment: I wish a kickstarter comes around with a laptop keyboard (like Thinkpad's) that is NOT compact & integrates touchpad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing some research, it turns out that laptop keyboards dont have the controller circuit. They are just the keys with the contacts, and that ribbon cable connects those contacts to the controller circuits which is inside the laptop.
So there is no way to convert that ribbon cable alone to a PS/2 interface. You need first the controller circuit, and only then you can think about converting it to a PS/2 plug.

And depending on how the keyboard's wire matrix is, the ribbon cable will have more or less contacts which match those on the controller. So you either need the exact same controller for the keyboard you want, or you can get a controller from a spare keyboard and manage to rewire the connections to the controller so they match correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution to enable laptop bottom case keyboards as USB keyboards using a Teensy microcontroller. The author has tested a wide variety of keyboard models, including Dell Inspiron, HP Presario, Sony Vaio, and IBM / Lenovo ThinkPad.

> A typical laptop keyboard relies on the motherboard for the scanning circuitry. I use a Teensy microcontroller mounted on a connector board to take over this function.

https://hackaday.com/2018/12/04/teensy-liberates-the-thinkpad-keyboard/

> Frank Adams liked the keyboard on his Lenovo ThinkPad T61 so much that he decided to design an adapter so he could use it over USB with the Teensy microcontroller. He got the Trackpoint working, and along the way managed to add support for a number of other laptop boards as well. Before you know it, he had a full-blown open source project on his hands.

Links for this project:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1PheqSNNP8
- https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-USB-Laptop-Keyboard-Controller/
- https://github.com/thedalles77/USB_Laptop_Keyboard_Controller

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are controller circuits that will convert a laptop keyboard to usb, i'm currently using one. I'm not sure where you can get them but they obviously exist. They are used to create keyboards for tablets.

[image: Laptop keyboard to usb]

Comment: Where did you get the one you are using?

Comment: I've searched Google, Ebay, Amazon etc. I can't find anything like this amazing mystery device. @matt-kingston where did this come from?

Comment: @matt where did u get this one that u are using.please share link.

Comment: Oh, those devices with black drop of plastic doing magic are just so great...

Comment: This is a classic case of XKCD DenverCoder9: https://xkcd.com/979/ . This post is the answer, but Matt Kingston was last seen in 2015.

Comment: @GetFree This appears to be similar to the controller from the USB keyboard/case disassembled in the video here: https://youtu.be/AKWheG8wKxM?t=216 - Found via [Daniel Suey's recent answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1387684/122042).

Comment: I purchased one of these and posted all details in an [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1447989/122042).

Answer (score 8):

I tracked down and purchased the [mystery board shown in the answer above](https://superuser.com/a/990231/122042).

The keyboard within the tablet case connects via ribbon cable to this PCB, which converts the laptop keyboard to micro USB.

It came from the `TA_Keyboard_9inKBCase_GPCT240` tablet keyboard case. This case is notable for having the "ZZZ" key, which you should look for if buying from a random website.

This is available on Amazon and eBay, etc., under titles similar to:

> 9" Carrying Case Tablet Stand With Keyboard & Stylus For 9" Tablets

The board is labeled `GL-NBK14-HY`. The ribbon is labeled `YT-K07 WJT-261`. Tablet keyboard case labeled `GPCT240`. Item number is possibly `223228583400`.

[image: board GL-NBK14-HY]

[image: ribbon YT-K07 WJT-261]

[image: keyboard case GPCT240]

[image: keyboard + board]

Happy to share, as the shipping label says:

> We don't believe in secrets, so feel free to tell all your friends about us!

I have not yet done any testing with other laptop ribbon cables plugged into this board. Would love to see any research done, especially on if it works with any ThinkPad laptop keyboards!

Answer (score 6):

I did little googling and found how it works inside. Basically every keyboard works the same, when a key is pressed, then current flows between two of the wires on the ribbon cable.

The controller circuit can be taken from any (old) keyboard and you would only need to solder the wires together. Of course then the keys would be probably mixed up randomly, but custom keyboard layout in OS would fix it.

Here are links for techies:

- http://multipledigression.com/type/together.html
- http://www.nastypixel.com/instantsoup/recipes/soundpad/sound-pad-build/
- http://www.modd3d.com/articles/item/keyboard-hack

Answer (score 6):

You just have to ask for it and a good computer shop will simply order it from their distributor.

Here is a [catalog of most Acer Laptop Keyboards](http://icecat.biz/index.cgi?language=en&lookup_text=acer+keyboard), please note that this is not a store but rather an extensive catalog, they share the same product code/name as the manufacturers/distributors.

To make the process easier, look for a product code at the bottom of your laptop keyboard.

[This keyboard on icecat](http://icecat.biz/EN/p/kbint00261/keyboards-desktops-keyboard-ui-5637502.html) is compatible with Aspire 4736G/4736Z Series, product code: `KB.INT00.261`.

---

Instructions from the [service guide hosted on icecat](http://pdfs.icecat.biz/pdf/26326601-1319-manual.pdf):

(**Remove power connector and power first!**)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Extensive walk thru +1

Comment: erm why did this answer gets 11 votes when it is off-topic to the question?

Comment: @Pacerier: Because I answered on [your original question](http://superuser.com/revisions/27bc6cfe-6aa6-4536-902c-68c0841e761a/view-source) which did not clearly state that. Writing the wrong questions gets you the wrong answers, it's not our fault given that multiple users did it this way. There is no way to remove this mess just because you changed the intention over time. To answer your adjusted question: You can look into USB keyboard of the same producer, they would most likely share the qualities of the laptop keyboard. But no, they don't usually make the exact same keyboard...

Comment: Tom I merged Pacerier's question with a related one, but this answer is no longer really relevant. I feel it should probably be removed. If you agree, flag it and we can delete it for you.

Comment: @nhinkle: Given the time spent in this answer and the people that have up-voted it, can you somehow revive the original question (the first revision) under the context of an anonymous user and solely migrate my answer back? It feels out of context here, but to just delete it feels weird given that it wasn't wrong in the first place...

Comment: @Tom unfortunately, migrations are not reversible by moderators. You would have to ask a Stack Exchange dev to do it. It seems your answer wasn't even fully relevant to the original question. Perhaps it would be better if you created a new question about it and did a self-answer, jeopardy style? I can ask a dev about migrating it, but I don't know how possible/worthwhile that is.

Comment: @nhinkle: [This is the original question](http://superuser.com/revisions/27bc6cfe-6aa6-4536-902c-68c0841e761a/view-source). He is asking for a separately sold laptop keyboard, which is commonly known as a replacement keyboard. He didn't specify whatsoever that it should've been used in an external manner. It was fully relevant until he changed the intention after it had been answered; so, the original question wasn't even a duplicate of this question. Can't you ask a dev in the Teacher Room what's best to do in this case? If you really want, I can place a Jeopardy Q tomorrow...

Comment: I know that the question's scope changed; regardless, it doesn't really do anybody any good to migrate it back, and I don't think it's worth bothering a dev about - it takes time, would require manual editing of the database, and doesn't really add much of anything. Why not just write a Community FAQ about how to replace a laptop's keyboard, and call it a day? Your answer is basically just a copied picture anyways, which is useful, but nothing you can't easily adapt to a new post.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is here...

Comment: @UpTheCreek: Because a moderator migrated it from [a more specific question](http://superuser.com/revisions/27bc6cfe-6aa6-4536-902c-68c0841e761a/) to a more general one, which shouldn't have happened. I've had 11 upvotes there and wish to retain that, the only solution here is to bring back the original state. This is left over from [one question to rule them all](http://meta.superuser.com/q/778) ([see also](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)). But as we know, **no one size fits all**! (see [Jeff's words](http://meta.superuser.com/a/1859))

Comment: Furthermore, this image or its information is not easily findable on Google; it's extracted from their service manual which you also need to know how to find. This expertise is worth its points. Answers should only be deleted if they were invalid *before* the migration, if you have to delete them *after* the migration then it just means that *the migration shouldn't have happened*...

Comment: @TomWijsman - it looks like a good answer :) Just not the one I was expecting to this question - almost unrelated! (I don't understand why it was moved)

Answer (score 5):

There's now a product available for easily using several different types of laptop keyboard ribbon cables via a USB interface.

Product number `QK-AK5`, possibly made by Rinbers Tech. Available on Amazon, eBay, AliExpress, etc., with titles such as:

> Universal Laptop Keyboard Tester Testing Device Machine Tool USB Interface Keyboard Test Tool

It's ostensibly a "testing" device, presumably to easily test refurbished laptop parts.

> Updated version: we updated the keyboard tester with 2 more connectors, one is used for testing keyboard of DELL TOSHIBA laptops, like Dell Inspiron N4110, 3521, 3421, Toshiba Satellite A300, L850, L600, C850, L50 and so on, the other is used for testing keyboard of Apple keyboard like a1278 1369 and so on, so this keyboard tester tool is very very useful for your business, actually, I think this tool could be used to test more than 90% laptop keyboard in the market.

[image: Notebook Keyboard Test Tool]

Answer (score 3):

Internal keyboards typically use a PS/2 interface, but the connectors are not designed in such a way that they could be used easily externally from the laptop. Here is an image of a keyboard being replaced; you can see how the keyboard is attached by a narrow ribbon cable. This is not an industry-standard connection, and varies from laptop to laptop.

[image: laptop keyboard ribbon]

If you are looking for a keyboard which feels like a laptop keyboard, there are some that exist. [Apple's keyboards](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/A) have a style almost identical to the popuplar "chiclet" style of keyboard found on many laptops today. They are however very expensive, and I don't personally like the aesthetic.

[image: apple keyboard]

Newegg sells [a wireless keyboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ImageGallery.aspx?CurImage=23-204-016-TS&ISList=23-204-016-S01,23-204-016-S02,23-204-016-S03,23-204-016-S04&S7ImageFlag=1&Item=N82E16823204016&Depa=0&WaterMark=1&Description=i-rocks%20RF-6520-BK%20Black%202.4GHz%20Wireless%20Ultra%20Slim%201.5%20AREA%20Keyboard) from i-rocks which is very similar to older non-chiclet laptop keyboards. I haven't personally used it, but it has decent reviews.

[image: newegg's keyboard]

Newegg also sells a [similar design from Rosewell](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823201033) which looks even more appealing to me:

[image: rosewill keyboard]

And Microsoft makes a very nice, spill-resistant, laptop-style keyboard as well, the [Digital Media Keyboard 3000](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823109201). You can probably find it from other retailers as well if you want. I've used one of these before and liked it very much.

[image: Microsoft keyboard]

Comment: Another thing I like about laptop keyboards is that they don't have the numpad. That thing just takes space.

Comment: what do you mean by spill-resistent? keyboards can't possibly be water-resistant right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not PS2.  PS2 only requires 4 wires...

Comment: Are internal keyboards connected through some internal USB, just like external keyboards are plugged into external USB slot?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but one that I've heard many times over the years and until recently never had a good answer for, but now I do so I'll share:

You can use a Ribbon Cable Breakout Board that requires soldering the ribbon cable on.  The best thing to start searching for a breakout board might be to look for ones for breaking out laptop LCDs for connecting to FPGAs (its a weirdly common thing).  The breakout board has a set of solder points spaced that match those on your keyboards ribbon cable, so you need to measure that and find a breakout board to match.  Once you have those wired up the breakout board will give you large enough points to attach wires to connect it to something like the [Teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/index.html), which can act as a usb keyboard.  You would need to write some code, but it is simple code, and hobby level, so most people can do it with a bit of reading and following a few tutorials.

The most difficult thing would be connecting the ribbon cable to the breakout board.  It can be done, but you may ruin a ribbon cable (and the laptop keyboard it is attached to) or a few in your attempts, so if you are going to try be prepared to buy more hardware in the case you don't get it right the first try.  Maybe try with some broken keyboards first (you can probably get some cheap from a PC recycling store).

This might be a good option for someone who has found a keyboard that really works well for them, and is committed to making it work outside the laptop it is designed for.

Everyone has their own taste in interface devices and it can be difficult to find a good fit for some people, so I hope this helps some of those with tastes/needs that do not fit into the usual spectrum of shelf-found products.

Answer (score 2):

The only stand-alone laptop-like keyboard I've seen is this: [Lenovo ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint](http://www.notebooksandmore.net/product_info.php?products_id=12187)

Comment: Link is Dead, this is why link only answers are not good, sweet keyboard by the way, seems to be several variations over the years...... https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-ThinkPad-Compact-Keyboard-TrackPoint/dp/B00F3U4TQS/ref=pd_sim_sbs_147_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GWBF2NSXEDFCR3MD2HRY

Answer (score 1):

A laptop keyboard connects via a ribbon cable, so you would first need to find some way to adapt that ribbon cable to a ps2 or USB connector.  Laptop keyboard are also very flat, so it would be difficult to type on in my opinion.  Here is basically what you would be dealing with:

[image]

Unless you like to make and modify stuff I would look harder for a real keyboard that you like... or maybe get a roll up keyboard or search for slim keyboards at [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com).

Answer (score 1):

Keysonic appears to be a company that make keyboards with "notebook" layouts, though they all appear to be wireless rather than USB, though I would expect them to come with a USB wireless converter.

While it may not exactly match your machine I suspect it is the closest you will get.

Check out the [Keysonic Compact Wireless Keyboard](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Keysonic-Wireless-Keyboard-Integrated-Frequency/dp/B000L10Y5E)

There is also the [Toshiba Slim Keyboard - Notebook Layout](http://www.techbuy.com.au/p/77284/KEYBOARD_ALL/Toshiba/PA1391U-1NKB.asp) that is very similar in style to a notebook keyboard but has a separate number pad.

In general though "notebook layout" keyboards do not appear to be very popular and I would not expect to find one that exactly matches your current keyboard, simply because there are likely to be too many slight variations of notebook keyboards and the design work necessary to turn every one of those in to full working keyboards would be insane.

The keyboard you see in front of you on your laptop is generally just a passive set of wires and contacts and to turn it in to a full USB keyboard would require a keyboard-USB controller, a case, cable and everything and given that there are already a lot of compact keyboards out there to choose from I would not expect any manufacturer to go to the effort.

Comment: ok btw the first link is broken..

Comment: @Pacerier, my real link (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Keysonic-Wireless-Keyboard-Integrated-Frequency/dp/B000L10Y5E) is being "fixed" automatically by the site, the "true" link works, the replacement one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I also like Laptop keyboards as opposed to regular ones.

I used to use an older version of this keyboard: http://www.gyration.com/index.php/us/products/in-air-micekeyboards/go-air-mouse.html#thumb4

Buying a wireless keyboard/mouse suite may not be what you want to do, especially if you are not fond of the wireless mouse idea, but the keyboard was pretty excellent (at least when I used it)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a replacement part, the best source is one of the several outfits that disassemble damaged laptops into component parts.

If you want a desktop keyboard that matches your laptop keyboard, lotsa luck.  I prefer a "compact" keyboard without the extra keypad, etc, and they are scarce as hen's teeth.  And the few you can find are poor quality or have the keys laid out strangely.  Used to be (maybe 10 years ago) that there was an outfit in Kentucky that made nice keyboards in various styles, but they went out of business, and now all you can find is the standard monstrosity, for the most part.

Comment: i don't want a replacement keyboard. so you mean those USB keyboards that are exact look-aliks as the replacement keyboards are not in the market?

Comment: I tried several years back to find a nice "compact" keyboard, similar to a laptop keyboard.  99% of the keyboards on the market are clones of the "AT" keyboard, with keypad and loads of extra keys.  I did find a couple that were compact, but they had screwy key layouts.  Unicomp, the outfit that bought out Lexmark's keyboard biz, and which had a nice assortment of keyboards at one time, was apparently sold to another outfit that has milked it as a cash cow for several years.  They still nominally exist, but advertise no compact keyboards other than a wireless one with a flaky layout.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a single solution.. laptop keyboards have different mappings and sized connectors.

There was an answer here that showed a controller/pcb that no one knew where to buy it.. the controller also appears in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKWheG8wKxM

The controller is within cheap ebay leather cased min keyboards with a micro usb.

Comment: Thank you for posting! This definitely seems to be the mystery board shown in the answer above: https://superuser.com/a/990231/122042

Answer (score 0):

This is the PCB harvested from a SK-8855 ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint.

- `SK8855_V0.6`
- Parts Number P/N: `812-00491-02A`

This is the ThinkPad / IBM / Lenovo part that allows you to convert a ThinkPad Keyboard to USB.

Keyboards from ThinkPad `T410 T420 T510 T520 W510 W520 X220` computer models can be plugged into this board and converted to USB.

[image: 812-00491-02A front]

[image: 812-00491-02A back]

The ThinkPad keyboard connector ribbon cable and socket is discussed and identified here:

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64112/how-to-find-socket-for-keyboard-connector/72550

Links that demonstrate swapping ThinkPad keyboards to USB and vice-versa using this board:

- http://tpholic.com/xe/ibmreport/11123707
- https://dingadinga.tistory.com/172
- http://ajax-chen.blogspot.com/2018/04/
- https://twitter.com/i/events/823087735451680768
- https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=66822